# Difference between require('mongoose').Mongoose and require('mongoose')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've noticed that certain libraries like
Mockgoose (https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose/blob/master/test/index.spec.js)
use require('mongoose').Mongoose to declare an instance of mongoose like this:

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;
var mongoose = new Mongoose();
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TestingDB');
```

However, most examples I've seen online does this to connect to a database:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TestingDB');
```

I just want to know if there's a difference between these two methods of getting an instance of mongoose or are they really two different ways to get the same thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between the two.

`require('mongoose')` returns an instance of `Mongoose`, and `new require('mongoose').Mongoose` gives you a new instance of `Mongoose` that isn't the same instance as the one returned from `require('mongoose')`. The latter is useful when a particular part of your app needs it's own instance of mongoose that doesn't conflict with the rest (which makes it perfect for unit testing)

In a typical application though you'll want to simply use `require('mongoose')` so that everywhere you use `require('mongoose')`, you'll get the same instance.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/index.js#L520

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!